# AVPlayerViewController in Node

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, arkit, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm playing around with ARKit a little and wanted to place a video inside of a SCNPlane. My issue is, that I don't see the players content at all. The controls with the correct durations etc are there, so the player seems to be set up correctly. Still, it is not showing up.

All the SO-Answers I found were solved by giving the playerLayer the correct size, but this is most certainly not my issue, because if I give the playerLayer a background color, it is shown (and in front of everything else, like it should be)

```
let videoPlayerController = AVVideoPlayerController()

private func handleFoundMagazine(_ imageAnchor: ARImageAnchor, _ node: SCNNode) {
    let size = imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize

    if let videoNode = createVideoNode(size: size) {
        videoNode.name = "Magazine Video"
        node.addChildNode(videoNode)
        node.opacity = 1
    }
}


private func createVideoNode(size: CGSize) -> SCNNode? {
    guard let videoPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Video_1_Alle", withExtension: "mp4") else { print("not found in ressource"); return nil }
    let videoItem = AVPlayerItem(url: videoPath)
    let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: videoItem)
    videoPlayerController.player = videoPlayer

    let avMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    avMaterial.diffuse.contents = videoPlayerController.view

    let videoPlane = SCNPlane(width: size.width, height: size.height)
    videoPlane.materials = [avMaterial]

    let videoNode = SCNNode(geometry: videoPlane)
    videoNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2

    print("successfully created Video Node")
    return videoNode
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

class AVVideoPlayerController: AVPlayerViewController {

  var playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
  var isPlaying = false

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = .red
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    setupPlayerLayer()
    player?.play()
  }

  fileprivate func setupPlayerLayer() {
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.player)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
    //playerLayer.backgroundColor = .blue
  }
}
```

Doesn't look too complex, right?

BTW: Once it lagged a little and then I was able to see the video, BEHIND the red Background of the viewcontrollers view.

---

Picture:
[image: No layer background]